# Transition between stateful service and external persistence in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure, orleans, azure-service-fabric

The Azure Service Fabric appears to be focused on scenarios in which all data can fit within RAM and persistence is used as a backing store. Reliable Services are designed to store information in Reliable Collections, which use a [log-checkpoint system](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections/) where logged information is written into RAM. Meanwhile, for Reliable Actors, the [default actor state provider](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-platform/#actor-state-provider-choices) is "the distributed Key-Value store provided by Service Fabric platform." This seems to indicate that the same limitations would apply.

There may, however, be situations in which one would like to use the Service Fabric for "hot data" but write "cold data" to some form of permanent storage. What are best practices for handling this transition?

In Orleans, this seems to be handled automatically, using a persistence store such as Azure tables. But it seems that a principal design purpose of the Service Fabric and the Reliable Collections are to avoid needing external services, thus enhancing data locality. The current documentation anticipates the possibility that one would want to move data into some permanent store for [disaster recovery and analytics](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-application-scenarios/), but it does not discuss the possibility of moving data back and forth between persistence-backed in-memory actors and more permanent forms of storage.

A possible answer is that the Service Fabric already does this. Maybe a Reliable Dictionary has some built-in mechanism for switching between persistence-backed in-memory storage and permanent storage.

Or, maybe the answer is that one must manage this oneself. One approach might be for an Actor to keep track of how "hot" it is and switch its persistence store as necessary. But this sacrifices one of the benefits of the Actor model, the automatic allocation and deallocation of actors. Similarly, we might periodically remove items from the Reliable Dictionary and add it to some other persistence store, and then add them back. Again, though, this requires knowledge of when it makes sense to make the transition.

A couple of examples may help crystallize this:

(1) Suppose that we are implementing a multiplayer game with many different "rooms." We don't need all the rooms in memory at once, but we need to move them into memory and use local persistence as a backup once players join them.

(2) Suppose that we are implementing an append-only B-Tree as part of a database. The temptation would be to have each B-Tree node be a stateful actor. We would like hot b-trees to remain in memory but of course the entire index can't be in memory. It seems that this is a core scenario that is already implemented for things like DocumentDB, but it's not clear to me from the documentation how one would do this.

A related question that I found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051408/understanding-when-to-use-stateful-services-and-when-to-rely-on-external-persist). But that question focuses on when to use Azure Service Fabric vs. external services. My question is on whether there is a need to transition between them, or whether Azure Service Fabric already has all the capability needed here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Key-Value store state provider does *not* require everything to be kept in memory. This provider actually stores the state of all actors on the local disk and the state is also replicated to the local disk on other nodes. So the KVS store is considered a persistent and reliable store.

In addition to that, the state of *active* actors is also stored in memory. When an actor hasn't been used in a while, it gets deactivated and garbage collected. When this happens, the in-memory copy is freed and only the copy on disk remains. When the actor is activated again, the state is fetched from disk and remains in memory as long as the actor is active.

Also, KVS is not the only built-in state provider. We also have the VolatileActorStateProvider (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-platform/#actor-state-provider-choices). This is the state provider that keeps everything in memory.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So, the KVS store differs from the reliable collections in not seeking to keep all state in memory all the time. (Or perhaps the reliable collections also sometimes page in and out of memory, despite the documentation that seems to suggest otherwise?) That makes much more sense. Of course, at some point the KVS store would run out of memory on disk, but I assume that this can be avoided through monitoring.

Comment: Reliable collections also persist their state on disk. The documentation on this page mentions it explicitly. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections/. "Persisted: Data is persisted to disk for durability against large-scale outages (for example, a datacenter power outage). ". Was there any place in the documentation that suggested otherwise?

Comment: Also, to address the concern about running out of disk space, you can read the article on scalability (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-concepts-scalability/) for strategies to scale your service and avoid this situation. Monitoring is also a good idea, as you already pointed out.

Comment: The documentation made clear that Key-Value store and reliable collections persisted data to disk. But it seemed to imply that the reliable collections would always be in memory too: "[E]ach state change is logged on disk and only applied in memory.... [When] the Reliable State Manager needs to truncate its log to make room for the newer records[, i]t will request the Reliable Collections to checkpoint their in-memory state." I wrongly inferred that state would always be preserved in memory. The documentation doesn't explain how state survives garbage collection.

Comment: From http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-quick-start/ : "Objects stored in Reliable Collections are kept in local memory in your service"

Answer (score 6):

The KvsActorStateProvider does indeed store actor state in a KeyValueStore which is a similar structure to the ReliableDictionary.

The first question I'd ask is whether you need to relegate old actors state to cold storage? The limitation of keeping everything in memory doesn't limit you to a total number of actors, but a total number per replica. So you must first consider the partitioning strategy so that your actors are distributed across a number of different replicas. As your demands grow you can then add more machines to the cluster and the ServiceFabric will orchestrate movements of the replicas to the new machines. For more information on partitioning of the Actor service, see http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-platform/

If you do want to use cold storage after some time, then you have a couple of options. Firstly, you could decorate your actors with a custom [ActorStateProviderAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.kvsactorstateproviderattribute.aspx) that returns your own implementation of an IActorStateProvider that can handle persistence as you decide.

Alternatively, you could handle it entirely within your Actor implementation. Hook into the [Actor Lifecycle](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-lifecycle/) and in OnDeactivateAsync such that when the instance is garbage collected, or use an [Actor Reminder](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-timers-reminders/) for some specified time in the future, to serialise the state and store in cold storage such as blob or table storage and null out the State property. The ActivateAsync override can then be used to retrieve this state from offline storage and deserialise.

Comment: This is very helpful. What remains puzzling to me is why the Reliable Actors framework includes garbage collection but then uses KvsActorStateProvider as the default (and I believe, only included) storage provider. If KvsActorStateProvider effectively keeps everything in RAM as well as on disk, doesn't that undo the benefits of garbage collection? Of course, there are benefits to moving actors between nodes, but usually we think of garbage collection as freeing up RAM memory.

Comment: What gets stored in the KVS is the state of a stateful actor. The actor object itself sits in memory and can have local variables which will get released from memory when the Actor is garbage collected.